# How to force Windows to rerun the user profile setup/upgrade procedure manually?

Tags: windows, windows-registry, windows-11, user-profiles, windows-11-upgrade

I was running Windows 11, but I guess this applies to Windows 10 as well.

I had a semi-broken user-profile on Windows 11 (start menu not opening, the whole taskbar reverted to the Win10 variant instead of the Win11 one) and was unable to fix it up manually. Creating a new user profile was too much of a hassle, so I kept going with it (can you imagine living without the start menu?...)... Until 22H2 finally got released.

After installing the 22H2 update and logging into the broken-profile, I was greeted with the "Hello, please wait while we setup your profile" prompt - similar to the one which is presented when a profile is just created and the user logs in for the first time. And after that automagically the profile was fixed without loosing any of my data!

Now, the question. I guess the underlying procedure between creating a new profile and upgrading an existing one is the same, so... How can I trigger it manually without actually upgrading the system? How does Windows determine after an upgrade that this profile should be re-setuped again to work correctly?

Triggering it manually will allow to easily fix some of the profile brokinesses without loosing data. So is there any clues about how to do it?

Comment: "How can I trigger it manually without actually upgrading the system?" - To my knowledge you can't.  What triggers the profile process is the installation of the upgrade

Comment: I guess there is no user friendly way to do it, indeed. I was rather thinking about tricking Windows in thinking that the profile wasn't updated after a Windows major update, so it runs the update as usually (because the said update is done on a per-profile basis no matter how much time passed since the Win update, and it seems there is somewhere some sort of flag which defines if the profile is already up-to-date or not).